# Antd how to do onClick on List or Card action?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hi i can't figure out how to set up the onclick function for the action below for Antd Card. Could someone help me pls? thanks.

```
const expand = () =>{
    console.log("expand")
  }

const IconText = ({ icon, text, cb }) => (
    <Space>
      <div onClick={e => cb}>
      {React.createElement(icon)}
      {text}
    </div>
    </Space>
  );


<Card style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}

    actions={[
     <IconText icon={ExpandOutlined} text="Expand" key="list-vertical-star-o" cb={()=>expand}/>,
     <IconText icon={MessageOutlined} text="Comments" key="list-vertical-like-o" />,
       ]}
    >
```

https://ant.design/components/card/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the callbacks  ( [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/support-more-content-configuration-antd-card-action-fnbq7))

```js
cb = {
  () => {
    expand("Comments");
  }
}
```

also  while binding:

```html
<div onClick={e=> cb}>
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Card, Avatar, Space } from "antd";
import {
  EditOutlined,
  EllipsisOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Meta } = Card;

const IconText = ({ icon, text, cb }) => (
  <Space>
    <div onClick={cb}>
      {/*React.createElement(icon)*/}

      {text}
    </div>
  </Space>
);

const expand = (text) => {
  console.log("expand", text);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    cover={
      <img
        alt="example"
        src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png"
      />
    }
    actions={[
      <IconText
        text="Expand"
        key="list-vertical-star-o"
        cb={() => {
          expand("Comments");
        }}
      />,
      <IconText text="Comments" key="list-vertical-like-o" />,

      <SettingOutlined key="setting" />,
      <EditOutlined key="edit" />,
      <EllipsisOutlined key="ellipsis" />
    ]}
  >
    <Meta
      avatar={
        <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
      }
      title="Card title"
      description="This is the description"
    />
  </Card>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
const ActionCard = (props) => {
  const expand = () => {
    console.log("expand")
  }
  
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}
      actions={[
        <span 
          key="list-vertical-star-o"
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            flex: 1,
            gap: 8,
          }}
          onClick={expand}
        >
          <ExpandOutlined /> 
          Expand
        </span>,
        <span 
        key="list-vertical-like-o"
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flex: 1,
          gap: 8,
        }}
      >
        <MessageOutlined /> 
        Comments
      </span>,
      ]}
    >
      your content here
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).